# How to compare 2 java POJO objects of the same class having 200+ fields?

Tags: java

**1/2 Context**

Please keep in mind this is for a legacy project and cannot really refactor/alter existing code/tables. Mostly have to write on top of existing code.

A class in our project (UserEvent) has more than 200 fields (~225). The object represents the table of the same name in the database and each field in the class represents each column. Fields/columns can be divided into 2 parts:

1. main columns (around 50 columns) - id, name, start date, end date, create date, bunch of foreign keys etc
2. secondary columns (around 170 columns) - so if this were defined today you'd have created one JSON column for this and be done with it. But the table was created a long time back (15 years), so to accommodate any dynamic input, we have a lot of placeholder columns, multiple columns of each datatype, like - number1, number2....number25, date1, date2.....date25, string1, string2......string25. These make up the secondary columns.

use case:

1. user updates an existing row from the UI and sends it to the backend (he may or may not change any value)
2. in the backend, we have to fetch the same row from db. so we have 2 objects of the same class - userEventUI and userEventDB.
3. in the existing code, all the main columns of both objects are being compared one by one in an if condition id==id && name==name && .....
4. if all are equal then we do not proceed further, if even one is different, we do some processing.

**2/2 My issue**

In step 3 above, so far we were only comparing the main columns and not the secondary columns. But now the requirement is to check for secondary columns too. I do not want to add 170 additional &&s to the existing IF condition. What other way is there? Two approaches that I have in mind:

1. Override equals and hashCode, that hasn't been done so far. The issue I have with the approach is that it is almost the same as the existing issue, have to write comparisons for 200+ fields.
2. Not a lot better from 1, but to add a hash function to the UserEvent class. The function will concatenate all the fields of the class and generate a hash using some algorithm (MD5 maybe). I can compare the hashes of userEventUI and userEventDB in step 3 to see if something is updated.

Is there some other way? Any opinions?

Comment: *A class in our project (UserEvent) has more than 200 fields* - well that is bad design.

Comment: why not just update the DB?

Comment: are you saying that the end user can modify 200 fields in one round trip ? Then I'm afraid it is not only the data model which is badly designed but also your UI

Comment: @ScaryWombat We update the DB at the end every time, irrespective of whether anything has changed or not. The comparison is done for some other heavy, time-consuming processing, sending data to other internal services, and some third-party apps. If the value has changed, then we have to do that process, if not, then we just update one table.

Comment: What are your concerns? Performance? Code readability? Time spent writing code?

Comment: Just an idea - serialize both objects with Jackson ObjectMapper and compare the resulted JSON strings?

Comment: @CodeScale The user usually updates 1 or 2 secondary columns at a time. But we don't know which columns are configured on the UI, so we have to check all. I accept it is bad design, but this is just the tip of the iceberg, we have multiple classes with 30-50k lines of code.

Comment: @RickyMo Code readability and performance. The code is already difficult to read, don't want to make it worse.

Comment: "have to write comparisons for 200+ fields. " If you want to check for equality you have to compare anyway...  If code readability is your concern you have to accept that your class structure is not good and fix it first

Comment: @Mar-Z iirc, Jackson is an external library, so cannot really use that. Would have been much easier if we were using spring. Something like that in core java?

Comment: Do you find [getDeclaredFields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--) useful?

Comment: You  could use lombok `@EqualsAndHashCode` that would generate convenient methods for you

Answer (score 2):

Using an equals method is definitely the way to go. You don't have to write it yourself. Your IDE can generate it, or you can use a tool like [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) to generate it at compile time. The latter has the advantage of automatically updating if fields are added or removed.

Comment: This is the way to go. Even if the first viable reaction should be "refactor it".

Comment: And just wanted to add: Whatever you do, *don't* solve this using reflection or even JSON serialization. It makes no sense, doesn't perform, and will certainly come back to bite you later.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only checking the equality of the data, I wouldn't recommend overriding *equals*.
This is typically used to determine object equality, which is a slightly different context.

Just create a separate procedure.

An optimal approach, considering the database will have numerous values, would be to create a class to implement the procedure.
This will allow for the re-use of the variables during iterative invocations, thus reducing memory consumption.

In this example I created a class, *UserEventUtil*, with a single method, *checkEquality*.
It utilizes *[reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)* to compare the opposing fields.

This should improve the scalability, and hence remove the requirement to explicitly type every field.

If you have any objects other than the basic *scalar* types here, you can just add them to the *if-conditional* checks, utilizing whatever data they may have to prove equality.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class UserEventUtil {
    UserEvent userEventA, userEventB;
    Field[] fieldsA, fieldsB;
    Field fieldA, fieldB;
    Class<?> type;
    String stringA, stringB;
    int index;

    public UserEventUtil(UserEvent userEventA, UserEvent userEventB) {
        this.userEventA = userEventA;
        this.userEventB = userEventB;
    }

    boolean checkEquality() throws IllegalAccessException {
        fieldsA = userEventA.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        fieldsB = userEventB.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (index = 0; index < fieldsA.length; index++) {
            fieldA = fieldsA[index];
            fieldB = fieldsB[index];
            type = fieldA.getType();
            if (type == String.class) {
                stringA = (String) fieldA.get(userEventA);
                stringB = (String) fieldB.get(userEventB);
                if (stringA == null && stringB == null) continue;
                if (stringA == null || stringB == null) return false;
                else if (!stringA.equals(stringB)) return false;
            } else if (type == int.class) {
                if (fieldA.getInt(userEventA) != fieldB.getInt(userEventB))
                    return false;
            } else if (type == float.class) {
                if (fieldA.getFloat(userEventA) != fieldB.getFloat(userEventB))
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And, to simulate the *UserEvent* class, I created a basic object with some bunk fields.

```java
class UserEvent {
    String valueA, valueB, valueC;
    int valueD, valueE, valueF;
    float valueG, valueH, valueI;
}
```

Here is an example of comparing three separate values.

```java
UserEvent userEventA = new UserEvent();
userEventA.valueA = "a";
userEventA.valueB = "b";
userEventA.valueC = "c";
userEventA.valueD = 1;
userEventA.valueE = 2;
userEventA.valueF = 3;
userEventA.valueG = 4.5f;
userEventA.valueH = 6.7f;
userEventA.valueI = 8.9f;

UserEvent userEventB = new UserEvent();
userEventB.valueA = "a";
userEventB.valueB = "b";
userEventB.valueC = "c";
userEventB.valueD = 1;
userEventB.valueE = 2;
userEventB.valueF = 3;
userEventB.valueG = 4.5f;
userEventB.valueH = 6.7f;
userEventB.valueI = 8.9f;

UserEvent userEventC = new UserEvent();
userEventC.valueA = null;
userEventC.valueB = "b";
userEventC.valueC = "c";
userEventC.valueD = 1;
userEventC.valueE = 2;
userEventC.valueF = 3;
userEventC.valueG = 4.5f;
userEventC.valueH = 6.7f;
userEventC.valueI = 8.9f;

UserEventUtil util;

util = new UserEventUtil(userEventA, userEventB);
System.out.println("util.checkEquality(), userEventA and userEventB = " + util.checkEquality());

util = new UserEventUtil(userEventB, userEventC);
System.out.println("util.checkEquality(), userEventB and userEventC = " + util.checkEquality());
```

Output

```
util.checkEquality(), userEventA and userEventB = true
util.checkEquality(), userEventB and userEventC = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare all fields in two objects of the same class with the help of [getDeclaredFields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--)

```java
public static <T> boolean compareObjects(T obj1, T obj2) throws IllegalAccessException {
    if (obj1 == null || obj2 == null || !obj1.getClass().equals(obj2.getClass())) {
        return false;
    }

    Field[] fields = obj1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        Object value1 = field.get(obj1);
        Object value2 = field.get(obj2);
        if (value1 == null && value2 != null || value1 != null && !value1.equals(value2)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Alternatively make this as the `equals` function of your specific class.

Comment: IMO This is not making the code more "readable"

Comment: @CodeScale Seems pretty obvious what the thing does. And I haven't done much java programming in a long while. Certainly better than having 200 explicit comparisons (is any field missing? is there a typo somewhere? good luck finding those problems)

Comment: @Voo Missing fields and typo are not concerns anymore with IDE.

Comment: @Code Which IDE tells you "only 199 of 200 fields are part of this comparison"? Sure you can use it to generate the code once, but good luck noticing when a new field is added afterwards that someone forgot to extend the equals check.

Comment: @Voo to be honest we have to admit that whatever the option you take it does not solve the main problem here. Your concern is not mine because this solution is just supporting the existing bad design.

Comment: @Code The great thing about legacy code is that you have to do your best in an imperfect environment. My problem was simply with the claim that 200 explicit comparisons would be more readable than a generic solution when in fact you'd just have to have faith that the programmer used the right tool correctly to generate the code - that's the opposite of readable.

Comment: Prepare the class to be ready to support additional attributes on top of already 200 attributes is not my vision of "doing our best". I'm not blaming here just personal opinion even if I respect your point and somehow understand it.

Comment: I admit I would encourage refactoring or even explicit comparison more than this "solution". But someone have to come up with some way to get the job done in the authentic situation. We've all been there as an employee... Just raising another possible option here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following to compare if they are equal using `GSON` lib

```
public static boolean comparePOJO(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    return new Gson().toJson(obj1).equals(new Gson().toJson(obj2));
}
```

Comment: How this might be more efficient than classic equals() ?

Comment: @CodeScale it can't

Comment: People downvoting this answer, but honestly, it is not that bad. It is the shortest among all answers and uses a smart trick, i.e. converting the POJO to JSON. People argue that it is inefficient, but the price paid is probably in the milliseconds needed for constructing the JSON and comparing it. All modern machines can do this blazingly fast. To really argue about inefficiencies, the author needs to tell us *how often* comparison between 2 objects will be called.